# Tableview is blank

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I have a tableview controller on my storyboard. I customized it in Xcode to have static cells and also added some cells to it. When running, my table is empty, I can not see my static cells.

The main steps I did:

- added tableview controller to the storyboard
- added UITableViewController file
- set class of my tableview to my added tableviewcontroller class
- set content mode to static cells
- added some cells to the list
- implemented numberOfSectionsInTableView (return 1)
- implemented numberOfRowsInSection (return 5)

I can see my tablewviewcontroller, but table is blank.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about pasting the code here? It would make spotting mistakes easier ;-)

Comment: For table views with static cells, you must not implement any of the table view data source methods. If you remove those, does it work?

Comment: Thanks jrturton, that was the problem: cellForRowAtIndexPath was implemented automatically by Xcode and wasn't commented out. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom glad it helped, I've posted it as an answer, in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For table views with static cells, you must not implement any of the table view data source methods. If you remove those, you should be OK.